# Find the time complexity of nested loops

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

I want to find the time complexity of `my_func()`. Input to this function is a list of integers. Length of the list is N.

**Code:**

```
def my_func(lst: List[int], N: int):
    if N < 4:
        return 0
    else:
        lim = int(N/2) + 1
        for p_len in range(2, lim): # outer for loop
            pattern = lst[:p_len]
            for i in range(p_len, N, p_len): # inner for loop
                if pattern != lst[i:i+p_len]:
                    break
            else:
                return 1 
        return 0
```

**My Analysis:**
Inner for loop runs [image: N/p_len] times.
Outer for loop runs [image: N/2] times.
Hence,
[image: T(n) = N/1 + N/2 + N/3 + ... + N/(N/2)]

[image: T(n) = N(1/1 + 1/2 + ... + 1/(N/2)]

[image: T(N) = N log (N/2)]

[image: T(N) = O(n log n)]


Is this a correct analysis?

Comment: @DerekEden `i` should start with the value of `p_len`, each iteration it increments by `p_len`. Let N=50, and p_len=2,  then i=2,4,6,8,....50. But if N=50 and p_len=3 then i=3,6,9,....51

Comment: @DerekEden You are mistaken. The arguments in order are start, end, step.

Comment: It's O(N^2), because `pattern != lst[i:i+p_len]` takes `p_le`n time to slice and compare the elements, so the inner loop is N time.

Comment: What does the function do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following analysis shows the time complexity of the algorithm:

[image]

Based on the comments, in the worst case, inside the inner loop will run in `O(p_e)` which is the number of comparisons of the `pattern` with the whole of the list. `p_e` in the above equation is equal to `p_{len}`. We know that the inner loop will iterate `n/p_e` times (as the step of increasing is `n/p_e`).

Comment: So my analysis was incorrect? Can you tell where it went wrong? And why did you used Theta instead of Big O, For some inputs, that function can take less than n log n.

Comment: @ShubhamGaikwad Incorrectness for the exact part of the analysis. For example you used $N$ which is not correct. There is no loop for `n`. For `\Theta` as there are two nested loops for all `N > 4`, these two loops wil be run without no condiction. Hence, besides it is `O(n log n)`, in a tighter bound, it is in `Theta(n log(n))` as well.

Comment: I used `N`, but it should have been `N - i`. Is this because `i` cannot be ignored? It indirectly depends on `N`. And what if the input given is : lst = [1, 2, 1, 2], N=4. The inner loop is exhausted (not executing break statement) causing it to execute else part of inner for, which will immediately terminate the function `my_func`.

Comment: Solving (N-1)/1  + (N-2)/2  + ...  + (N - N/2 ) / (N/2) would be difficult. The way you used summation was nice way to get around it.

Comment: Using N instead of N-i was incorrect, but overall approach is good, isn't it?

Comment: The slicing and comparison `pattern != list[i:i+p_len]` takes `p_len` time, so the inner loop  takes N time in the worst case where all the list elements are the same.

Comment: @PaulHankin you're right. Thanks for your comment. It's updated.

Comment: Hmm, now I don't understand your first step. Why 2i, 3i, etc, instead of always i? Btw I'd pick a different letter, as i is used in the code for something else, which is confusing.

Comment: I know, and that's what I find suboptimal. And what about 2i etc? Now you end up with an unnecessarily *big* complexity class. The function is O(n^2), and the analysis is much simpler than you make it.

Comment: @superbrain No, it's `O(n^2 log(n))` because of the first term.

Comment: Not sure what "first term" you mean, but you're wrong. It's O(n^2). I suspect you misread what the code is doing.

Comment: I have same questions as pointed out by @superbrain. Using `i` in analysis is confusing. Also, I cannot understand `i+2i+3i+ (n/i) * i`. Can anyone explain in detail how do we get all these terms?

Answer (score 1):

Worst case is like `[0]*(N-1) + [1]`, where the outer loop runs N/2 times and the inner loop checks the pattern against the whole list, so the inner loop takes O(N) and thus your total time is only O(N<sup>2</sup>).

In other words, you're right that the inner for loop runs (up to) N/p_len times, but you forgot that each time takes O(p_len). Neither slice creation nor slice comparison are O(1). So you have (N/p_len)*p_len=N for the inner loop.

Comment: Can you explain how much time it take for:
**1.** lst[0] or lst[x] where x is some valid index
**2.** lst[x : x+5] 
**3.** new_lst = lst[5: 10]

Comment: @ShubhamGaikwad All of those are O(1) because you used constant slice lengths. But for example `lst[i:j]` is O(j-i).